# can not create build for android in ionic

Tags: ionic2

I am on a Linux system and I have android sdk installed on it.

I am trying to build an apk but my build process is stuck without any warnings and errors. I have tried a couple of times now but nothing moves.

What could be the reasons and how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: is this working? `ionic serve`

Comment: @Sampath: Yes, ionic serve works fine

Comment: have you set ANDROID_PATH and JAVA_HOME?

Comment: @suraj: Yes,  echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
simran@Simran:~$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/simran/Android/Sdk